# WFS altimetric curves that intersect geometry?

Tags: wfs, query, getfeature

I have a WFS with altimetric curves and I would like to perform a spatial query. I would like to load from the WFS only curves that intersect or overlap a geometry from a shapefile, so only curves of a specific region.
I've tried with something like this:

```
intersection( $geometry , geometry( getFeature( "nameoflayer", "nameofattribute", 'valueinword' )))
```

But it doesn't work, I obtain a layer with curves attributes from the WFS ($geometry) but it is empty.

I've tried also with other operator like intersect but it doesn't work

How could I do it?